# Transfering files (pdf etc) from phone or pc to the samsung gear s2

Tags: file, tizen, transfer

I'm trying to transfer some pdf files (and other file formats in the future) from my pc/phone(galaxy s6) to my gear s2 classic. The gear companion app allows you to sync with your device only music or image files. I've been trying to put in my device some pdf files without succeeding. I've tried the sdb tools from the tizen studio but i couldn't get right the permissions so the memory was always read-only. Then i thought downloading the files would be easier but there is no app in the store for dropbox, googledrive etc. Have anyone succeeded at pushing files in the internal memory of the gear s2 classic?

Comment: have you checked the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

[Accessory SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory#5) allows you to transfer files between devices using any type of connectivity supported by the Samsung Accessory Service Framework. You can, for example, develop applications that record a voice memo and send it to the smart device (for example, the Voice Memo application on the Gear sends the recorded memo to the Galaxy Note 3 device).

With Accessory File Transfer, you can send files of any size over all connectivity types supported by the Samsung Accessory Service Framework.

Find

- [Programming Guide](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory/guide)
- [API Reference](http://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/sms/accessory/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 apps from Gear App Studio.

1. Install on phone [Gear File Transfer Companion](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gear.watch.studio.gearfiletransfer.sender&hl=en_US)
2. Install on watch *Gear File Manager Pro* (paid app 2$).
3. Upload ur files on phone into folder /GearFileManagerSender
4. On watch start *File Manager Pro*.
5. On watch go to *Download* folder - u will see extra option *Receive File From Phone*.
6. Touch file(s) you want to send on phone to start transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can change the extension from (*).pdf to (*).mp3 and then transfer the the file as a music using galaxy wearable, then browse to the music folder in your watch to find the file.